# How to implement M:N to M:N in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this kind of relationship in the database as follows, which I even don't know how to name:

[image]

Doctrine generates 3 entities, which is right, creates proper mappings for t1-t2 relation, but then uses nonexisting entity t1_has_t2 for t3-t3_has_t1_has_t2 relation. Is there a way to implement this kind of relationship in Doctrine without turning t1_has_t2 into useless entity.

Comment: @nii: Could you provide a real-world example for this schema?

Comment: @SBH, well, thanks for saving my time.

Comment: @lxg, this is an extract from the power grid model, t1 represents feeder, t2 -- power line, t3 -- connected to the power line's feeder hardware, think breaker or current transformer.